# Overriding arithmetic operators on Int via implicit conversions

Tags: scala

Say that, for aesthetical reasons, I want to be able to write:

```
3 / 4
```

and have / be a method on a class that there exists an implicit conversion from Int to, e.g.:

```
class Foo(val i: Int) {
  def /(that: Int) = // something
}

implicit def intToFoo(i: Int) = new Foo(i)
```

Is this at all possible, i.e. is it possible to "disable" the / method on Int?

Comment: Not enough of a Scala expert to tell you whether you CAN do this, but I can tell you SHOULD NOT do this.  Unless you are trying to construct "Scala Puzzlers" or something, you are just buying a lot of trouble at a steep discount.

Comment: To give some context, what I'm trying to do is write a URL matcher where you can specify URL patterns in the form of e.g. "foo/bar" / 34 / "some/thing". Obviously I could you \ or anything else, but "foo/bar" \ 34 \ "some/thing" looks a bit weird. I think the usage of / should be quite clear to any reader of the code in this context.

Comment: Note that in your comment example, the implicit conversion would be String to Foo, not Int

Comment: Both. (I.e. to some parallel class.) Note that the example given in the question has been simplified for brevity and does not completely implement the application sketched in the comment. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short:  No, you can't.

Implicit resolution will only take place if you attempt to call a method that doesn't already exist.

A more "idiomatic" solution would be to create your own pseudo-number type, something like:

```
case class Rational(a: Int, b: Int) {
  // other methods
}

val foo = Rational(3, 4)
```

or

```
case class Path(value: String) {
  def /(other: String): Path = ...
}

val p = Path("3") / "4"
```

Comment: I want to literally write 3 / 4, but the meaning of / is not intended to be numeric division, but rather path division. (See comment to question.)

Comment: Then create a new class taking the 3 as a constructor param, and define / on *that*

Comment: Might as well just do "3" / "4". Again, a matter of aestetics. Point is to make it a clean a DSL as possible with minimal clutter. Simplest is then probably e.g. "foo" / n(3) / n(4) etc. with an implicit conversion from case class n(i: Int) to a general item class. Still looks ugly to me. Then again, specifying literal ints in a URL pattern might prove to be quite useless in practice (i.e. why not just use "foo/bar/3/4/some/thing"), so the question might only have academic interest. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason that something like

```
trait PathElement[T] { val value: T }
case class IntElement(value: Int) extends PathElement[Int]
case class StringElement(value: String) extends PathElement[String]

case class Path(parts: Seq[PathElement[_]]) {
   def /(other: Path): Path = copy(parts = parts ++ other.parts)
}
object Path {
   def apply(part: PathElement[_]): Path = Path(List(part))
   implicit def int2path(i: Int): Path = Path(IntElement(i))
   implicit def str2path(s: String): Path = Path(StringElement(s))
}
```

wouldn't work for you?  This would allow you to write, for example,

```
import Path._
"foo" / 3 / 4 / "bar"
```

This works because String does not have its own `/` method, so the first `"foo"` is implicitly converted to a `Path`.  If you were starting a `Path` with an `Int`, you'd have to convert it explicitly, but you'd get any other `Int`s for free.

Comment: That's an excellent point that I didn't really consider, that the problem only arises when the Int is the first in the chain. Solves the problem for most practical purposes. (Given there are any.) :)

Answer (score 1):

I can of course only guess what you really want to accomplish but I assume you don’t just want to match concrete URLs but also extract information from given strings. E.g. when given `"/foo/21"` you don’t just want to know that this matches some `"foo" / 21` but you want to do something with the value of 21.

I’ve found the URI matching process in Lift to be quite useful, so maybe that fits your use case. (I’m using a very simplified version, of course.) It’s done with Lists there which makes matching a little easier but it also means you’ll have to use `::` instead of  `/`.

But that’s not the point: what I want to show is the advantage of *not* using implicit conversions and the power of extractors

```
object AsInt {
 def unapply(i: String): Option[Int] = try {
    Some(i.toInt)
  } catch {
    case e: java.lang.NumberFormatException => None
  }
}

def matchUrl(url: String) = {
  val req:List[String] = url.split('/').toList.drop(1)
  req match {
    case "foo" :: "bar" :: Nil => println("bar")
    case "foo" :: AsInt(i) :: Nil => println("The square is " + i*i)
    case "foo" :: s :: Nil => println("No int")
    case _ => println("fail")
  }
}

matchUrl("/foo/21")
matchUrl("/foo/b")
matchUrl("/foo/bar")
matchUrl("/foobar")

// prints:
// The square is 441
// No int
// bar
// fail
```

In short, using the `AsInt` extractor instead of an implicit conversion of `Int` to `String` you can actually retrieve the integer value from the string if and only if it is convertible and of course use it immediately. Obviously, if you don’t like the naming, you can change it to something more unobtrusive but if you really want to do url matching, you maybe should not convert everything implicitly.

Comment: Actually that's not quite what I'm trying to do, it's rather to specify the url pattern in the simplest possible way, a la Scalatra but with typed elements instead of specifying everything as a string. Now, this is relatively trivial to achieve, I just got stumped on the "/ method on Int" part.