# Overloading the existing `toInt` method

Tags: scala, overloading, enrich-my-library

The `toInt` method in `StringLike` doesn't take any arguments, and can only parse in decimal. So to parse binary, hex etc we need to resort to Java's `Integer#parseInt(String s, int radix)`.

In an attempt to remedy this state of affairs, I tried the following

```
implicit def strToToIntable(s: String) = new {
  def toInt(n: Int) = Integer.parseInt(s, n)
}
```

However,

```
"101".toInt(2)
```

causes the REPL compiler to "crash spectacularly" and doesn't work in compiled code either.

Is there some restriction on overloading existing methods using the "enrich my library" pattern?

Comment: Are you sure your new tag, ["pimping"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimping), is appropriate?

Comment: @tomasz: if I got an upvote for every time I crashed the REPL, I'd have 100000 reputation by now..

Comment: A compiler crash is never* the result of bad code, only of bad compiler. Or, in other words, the bug is in the compiler. * Well, there's a few exceptions where, though the compiler really shouldn't crash, the code is not correct either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the implicit, running `"101".toInt(2)` causes REPL to tell me that Int does not take parameters. So I guess what is happening is that it's running `"101".toInt`, then trying to call `apply(2)` on that, which doesn't make sense. I'd suggest a subtle rename of your pimped `toInt` to avoid the problem.

**edit**

I just had some success of my own. I explicitly defined a pimped string class as

```
class StrToRadixInt(s:String) {
  def toInt(radix: Int) = Integer.parseInt(s,radix)
}

implicit def strToToIntable(s:String) = new StrToRadixInt(s)
```

And REPL was happy:

```
scala> "101".toInt(2)
res4: Int = 5
```

Comment: It seems that scala does not want to facilitate overloading methods via implicits: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480250/scala-pimp-my-library-with-overloads and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443783/overriding-arithmetic-operators-on-int-via-implicit-conversions

Comment: The answer is in the links provided above, so accepting this one

Answer (score 1):

The REPL shouldn't crash--that's a bug.  But even so, overloading of names is somewhat discouraged and also not supported in some contexts.  Just use a different name:

```
implicit def parseBase(s: String) = new { def base(b: Int) = Integer.parseInt(s,b) }

scala> "10110" base 2
res1: Int = 22
```