# Scala Implicit Conversion Function Name Clashes

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am working with a simple complex number case class in Scala and would like to create an add function that works between complex numbers, doubles and ints. Below is a simple example of a working solution:

```
case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double) 

implicit def toComplex[A](n: A)(implicit f: A => Double): Complex = Complex(n, 0)

implicit class NumberWithAdd[A](n: A)(implicit f: A => Complex) {
    def add(m: Complex) = Complex(n.re + m.re, n.im + m.im)
}
```

Note I am deliberately not including the add function in the complex case class. Using the above I can do all of this:

```
scala> val z = Complex(1, 2); val w = Complex(2, 3)
z: Complex = Complex(1.0,2.0)
w: Complex = Complex(2.0,3.0)

scala> z add w
res5: Complex = Complex(3.0,5.0)

scala> z add 1
res6: Complex = Complex(2.0,2.0)

scala> 1 add z
res7: Complex = Complex(2.0,2.0)
```

I'd like to use '+' instead of 'add, but however this does not work. I get the following error:

```
Error:(14, 4) value + is not a member of A$A288.this.Complex
              z + 1
               ^
```

Both `z + w` and `1 + z` still work however.

What I'd like to know is why does changing the function name from 'add' to '+' break this? Is there an alternate route to getting this functionality (without simply putting the add function in the complex case class)? Any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit - Motivation

I'm playing around with monoids and other algebraic structures. I would like to be able to generalise the '...WithAdd' function to automatically work for any class that has a corresponding monoid:

```
trait Monoid[A] {
    val identity: A

    def op(x: A, y: A): A
}

implicit class withOp[A](n: A)(implicit val monoid: Monoid[A]) {
    def +(m: A): A = monoid.op(n, m)
}

case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double) {
    override def toString: String = re + " + " + im + "i"
}

class ComplexMonoid extends Monoid[Complex] {
    val identity = Complex(0, 0)

    def op(z: Complex, w: Complex): Complex = {
        Complex(z.re + w.re, z.im + w.im)
    }
}

implicit val complexMonoid = new ComplexMonoid
```

Using the above I can now do `Complex(1, 2) + Complex(3, 1)` giving `Complex = 4.0 + 3.0i`. This is great for code reuse as I could now add extra functions to the Monoid and withAdd function (such as appling op n times to an element, giving the power function for multiplication) and it would work for any case class that has a corresponding monoid. It is only with complex numbers and trying to incorporate doubles, ints, etc., that I then run into the problem above.

Comment: it's not possible to add a method that already exist by implicit conversions http://stackoverflow.com/a/4444122/1594980

Comment: The question you've linked to is trying to implicitly override a function with the same signature. None of the types Int, Double or my Complex class has a method + with one parameter of type Complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular `class`, not a `case class`. Then it would be easy to create methods to add or subtract these Complex numbers, like:

```
class Complex(val real : Double, val imag : Double) {

  def +(that: Complex) =
            new Complex(this.real + that.real, this.imag + that.imag)

  def -(that: Complex) =
            new Complex(this.real - that.real, this.imag - that.imag)

  override def toString = real + " + " + imag + "i"

}
```

As [the source page](https://dzone.com/articles/operator-overloading-scala) shows, it will now support something that looks like operator overloading (it's not, because `+` and `-` are functions and not operators).

The problem with `implicit class NumberWithAdd` and its method `+` is that the same method also exist in number classes such as `Int` and `Double`. The `+` method of `NumberWithAdd` basically allows you to start with a number that can be casted to `Complex` and add a `Complex` object to that first item. That is, the left hand value can be anything (as long as it can be converted) and the right hand value must be `Complex`.

That works great for `w + z` (no need to convert `w`) and `1 + z` (implicit conversion for `Int` to `Complex` is available). It fails for `z + 1` because `+` is not available in the class `Complex` .
Since `z + 1` is actually `z.+(1)`, Scala will look for other possible matches for `+(i: Int)` in classes that `Complex` can be converted into. It also checks `NumberWithAdd`, which does have a `+` function but that one required a `Complex` as right hand value. (It would match a function that requires an `Int` as right hand value.) There are other functions named `+` that do accept `Int`, but there's no conversion from `Complex` to what those functions want as left hand values.

The same definition of `+` does work when it's in the (case) class `Complex`. In that case, both `w + z` and `z + 1` simply use that definition. The case `1 + z` is now a little more complicated. Since `Int` does not have a function `+` that accepts a `Complex` value, Scala will find the one that does (in `Complex`) and determines whether or not it is possible to convert `Int` into `Complex`. That is possible using the implicit functions, the conversion takes place and the function is executed.

When the function `+` in the class `NumberWithAdd` is renamed `add`, there's no confusion with functions in `Int` because `Int` does not have a function `+`. So Scala will try harder to apply the function `add` and it will do the `Int` to `Complex` conversion. It will even do that conversion when you try `1 add 2`.

Note: My explanations may not fully describe the actual inner workings.

Comment: I know that this is a solution but I mentioned in my question that I don't want to have the functions contained in the case class. Part of my question is whether there is an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: @Tom I've expanded my answer a bit. That should hopefully clarify things more.

Comment: So, it would appear that if we don't/can't modify `class Complex`, then all we need to do to make `z + 1` work is add `def +(i: Int): Complex = this.+(toComplex(i))` to the `NumberWithAdd` class. But that will only cover `z + 1` (Int).  We'd have to add the same kind of thing to cover `z + 1L` (Long), and `z + 1.1` (Double), etc. _*sigh*_

Comment: @Arjan Thanks for spending the time to flesh out your answer. It seems like  getting a different solution will be harder than I thought.

Comment: @jwvh I guess there's a reason why classes like `Int` and `Double` have several functions `+` which all accept a different argument (and have a different return type).

Comment: @jvwh Your solution works but yeah... can get a bit icky. I'm gonna add a section to my question about the motivation behind this which might shine some light on my restriction about not having it in the Complex class (and also why your solution would complicate things to).